# C#/WPF: Why is TabItem.IsFocused returning null

Tags: c#, wpf

i have code like

```
e.CanExecute = tabEditor.IsFocused;
```

but at runtime, i get a null reference exception error. but in the docs, `IsFocused` returns only true or false, why is this happening? btw, `tabEditor` is a `<TabItem>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that either `e` or `tabEditor` is null, i.e., they weren't assigned to an object anywhere (or otherwise explicitly assigned to `null`). If the code is in an event handler, it's possible that the framework hasn't initialized all the variables by the time the event handler is called, in which case you might want to check for null.

Comment: `tabEditor` is null, but why? the code is inside a `Bold_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)` and tabEditor refers to `<TabItem Header="Editor" x:Name="tabEditor">` a TabItem inside my XAML. also you may have noticed from the function signature that i am using Routed Commands. i also noticed that i have not explicitly called the command yet. the error is produced on application start